# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Items.Restrict - not working correctly

Tags: c#, mapi

I can pull email, walk through them, mark them as read, even sort.   However, when I tried to restrict by ReceivedTime, it doesn't seem to be working.  I get nothing back no matter what date/time I put in.  I know ReceivedTime is valid based on the Sort works when I remove the restrict.  Any suggestions?

```
Application app = new Application();
NameSpace outlookNs = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Folders folders = outlookNs.Folders[ohOptions.PSTName].Folders
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Items items = folders["Inbox"].Items;

DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.Subtract(new TimeSpan(1,0,0));
items = items.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] > '" + dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt") + "'");

items.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", OlSortOrder.olAscending);

foreach (MailItem item in items)
{
    String from = item.SenderEmailAddress;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found the problem.  Only took three days as there doesn't seem to be anything that mentions formatting for these date/times.  It seems it doesn't like the seconds or the AM/PM to be there.   Using military time and stripping the seconds allows it to work correctly.

```
items = items.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] > '" + dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm") + "'");
```

Comment: Using this exact line and it's not working for me. I wish they'd document this better, simply finding the date format is such a pain.

Comment: This article simply uses DateTime.ToString("g") which also works for me.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg619398.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the current locale date format is really MM/dd/yyyy, not dd/MM/yyyy.

Comment: Checked and is not the problem.